# Google spell check http://www.google.com/tbproxy/spell? throws 404 error

Tags: jquery, .net, jquery-plugins, spell-checking

I am using jquery.spellchecker.js in my .net application to check the spellings typed by the users in the textarea. This plugin connects to http://www.google.com/tbproxy/spell? for doing the spell check. The code was working as expected till yesterday but all of a sudden it stopped working today. I am receiving a 404 error from this site and my code shows the following pop up

[image]

Any idea if the URL has been changed? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Service has started working now. Please check.. :)

Comment: Its up now! Thanks for informing.

Comment: If anyone is interest this many years later, Google discontinued this unofficial API around 2013 / 2014.