# google spell check giving 404 error

Tags: spell-checking, spelling

We are using GoogieSpell hitting this site (http://www.google.com/tbproxy/spell) and it had been working fine, however this url is now giving a 404 error.  I've seen some posts where people are complaining about the same issue, then someone responded saying service is running again.

[Google spell check http://www.google.com/tbproxy/spell? throws 404 error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15805568/google-spell-check-http-www-google-com-tbproxy-spell-throws-404-error)

It is clearly down.  Please advise.  Has this service been moved?

Comment: have you asked directly to them?

Answer (score 0):

Right now it is not available. It's a probably a problem in google

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at this...

https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chat/CPb0PYllbE8

Comment: That link is no longer available. I wonder what it said? (I'm aware this is 10 years ago)